# How to pass more parameters for socket.on()

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

For socket.on("someChannel", handler), I hope to extract out my handler function to another file. As such, they need to be passed in the socket obj and some more additional info.

Like:

```
socket.on("myEvt", myEvtHandler);

myEvtHandler(socket, additionalInfo, data) {//some stuff here}
```

But I can't. The best I can think of is to do closure:

```
(function(socket, addtionalInfo) {
    socket.on("myEvt", function(data) {
        myEvtHandler(socket, addtionalInfo, data);
    });
})(socket, addtionalInfo);
```

Is this correct? Are there better ways?

Comment: Did you verify that `this` in the `.on` handler isn't the socket itself? if not, you can just `socket.on('myevet', myEvtHandler.bind(socket));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a partial function using `bind`:

```
socket.on("myEvt", myEvtHandler.bind(null, socket, additionalInfo));
```

The `bind()` will return a function with the first two arguments already 'filled in'. The first argument passed to `bind()` (`null` in this case) is going to be the `this` object in your handler ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)).

Any additional arguments passed by `socket.io` to the handler will be available from the third argument onwards:

```
function myEvtHandler(socket, additionalInfo, data) { ... }
```

Similarly, this would do (almost) the same:

```
socket.on("myEvt", function(data) {
  myEvtHandler(socket, additionalInfo, data);
});
```

Comment: How about the original "data" argument, that by default passed in by the socket.on? How to access that?

Comment: @CharlesW. that's passed in as third argument to your handler